# ($n-1$) dimensional face $E $ of a $n$- dimensional interval is a set of measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis

1) I need help to show that the $(n-1)$ dimensional face $E$ of an $n$ dimensional interval is a set of measure zero.

Now a set $E' \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set of measure zero if $\forall  \epsilon>0$ there is a countable collection $\{I_k\}$ of open intervals s.t.
$$
E' \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} v(I_k) \leq \epsilon.
$$

So, let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  And let $E$ be the face of $E'$, where $E'$ is $n$ dimensional.  From last night and now I'm stuck, maybe it will come to me.  I understand that surface has a volume zero, but why should this definition sound so different?

I am trying to work on this but any input is very welcome.

2) Also, if $(a,b)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $a^i < b^i$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, then I need to show that $(a,b)$ is not of measure zero.

Maybe once I solve 1) this will be easier on me, but I have a feeling this might need some contrapositive proof.

Comment: When you say $n$-dimensional interval, I imagine that you talking about some $E' = [a_1, b_1] \times \cdots \times [a_n, b_n]$.  Is this the space that you have in mind?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m_{n-1}(E)$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional measure of $E$. Let $\eta>0$. There exist $n$-dimensional interval $I(E)$ containing $E$, such that $m_n(I(E))<2\eta\cdot 2^{n-1}m_{n-1}(E)$, which can be arbitraly small for small $\eta$. (Certainly $m_n$ is a $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: This sounds very complicated answer. I need to solve it based on my definition.

Comment: @Klara: There exists ONE interval, containg $E$, and of measure less than $\epsilon$, as in your definition.

Comment: I think I understand what you wrote. I did it for 2 dim and then generalized. I think I have to really specify my intervals etc. Thank you so much.